# Phoenix/Elixir - Logger works in some modules, but not others

Tags: logging, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a phoenix app in which I'm logging events using the `Logger` module.

Outputs to console as expected when using like this in a controller:

```
#web/controllers/v1/some_controller.ex
defmodule API.V1.SomeController do
  use AgilePulse.Web, :controller
  require Logger
  plug AgilePulse.Plugs.Params when action in [:create]

  def create(conn, params) do
    Logger.info "#{inspect(conn)}"
  end

end
```

But outputs nothing when used like this:

```
#web/plugs/params.ex
defmodule AgilePulse.Plugs.Params do
  require Logger

  def init(opts), do: opts

  def call(%Plug.Conn{params: %{"data" => data}} = conn, _opts) do
    Logger.info "#{inspect(conn)}"
  end

  def call(conn, _opts), do: conn

end
```

Why is that? And how can you get it to work in this scenario?

Currently using Elixir 1.2 and Phoenix 1.2.1.

Comment: I would guess it is because the pattern does not match on the data correctly and you are actually using the second definition of `call/2`.

Comment: oh, interesting observation...let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the first `call/2` pattern in your Plug isn't matching and is just plain not being called.

Add a `Logger.info/1` call to the second `call/2` pattern and you should see it work as expected.

```
def call(conn, _opts) do
  Logger.info "Hello!"
  conn
end
```